# Jboss adding zecmd.war

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

When i start my jboss it is adding zecmd.war, iesvc.war and wstats.war in deploy/management folder. How to get rid of this.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

It's a worm, see:
[JBoss Worm Analysis in Details](http://eromang.zataz.com/2011/10/25/jboss-worm-analysis-in-details/)

And:
[Statement Regarding Security Threat to JBoss Application Server](http://community.jboss.org/blogs/mjc/2011/10/20/statement-regarding-security-threat-to-jboss-application-server)